# Send Chosen Selected Values Array to Controller - MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So, I have a view with a chosen search box, a button "Add" **(btn-default)** and a button "Edit" **(breadcrumb)** . When I click the Add button, the ajax sent me a table with the values (in this case, funcionaries) selected in the chosen text box.

**I want that**, when I click on the Edit button, send the chosen values (can be one, or hundreds of values) to another controller to return another view.

Don't want to use ajax because I want to use a new view on totally.

On the controller side, when I send the data with javascript, I always get null. Why?

**View**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn-default").on("click", function (event, params) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("EditarPonderacoesEspecial", "Sorteios")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            traditional: true,
            data: { bdoIds: $(".chosen-select").val() },
            success: function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                $("#MyDiv").empty();
                $("#MyDiv").html(responseText);
            },
            error: function () { }
        })
    });

    $(".breadcrumb").on("click",function (event, params) {
            bdoIds = $(".chosen-select").val();
            $.post("/Sorteios/EditarPonderacoesEspecialSecond/", bdoIds);
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult EditarPonderacoesEspecialSecond(string[] bdoIds)
{ 
    //do whatever I want with the bdoIds
    return View();
}
```

I had tried many different ways, but the controller always receive the parameter as null. What I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You could use something like JQuery to aggregate the selected values and then insert them into a hidden form and then submit the form. That way you are not using AJAX and the form can redirect the user to the other view you want to return.

Comment: @SimonH, sounds interesting! Do you have some tutorial for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller action is expecting an array of strings.

Assuming `.chosen-select` is a select list as that part is missing from the question.

First read the selected values into an object as follows:

```
var selectedValues = [];
$(".chosen-select :selected").each(function() {
  selectedValues.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Then send them as follows:

```
$(".breadcrumb").on("click",function (event, params) {
    var selectedValues = [];

    $(".chosen-select :selected").each(function() {
           selectedValues.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });

   $.post("/Sorteios/EditarPonderacoesEspecialSecond/", { bdoIds: selectedValues  });
});
```

Comment: Hutchonoid, where I send the data? In ajax? the ajax is for the other button, not for what I want! Should I remove the ajax part from the post?

Comment: @danielpm See update, is `.chosen-select` a select list?

Comment: Perfect! Hutchonoid, you're the best! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare Global array like

   ```
   var SelectedArray = new Array();
   ```
2. When you select multiple selectlist item each time push value in SelectedArray

   ```
   $('#ChosenId').chosen().change(function () {
   SelectedArray = $('#ChosenId').chosen().val();
   ```

   });
3. Then your ajax data is like

   data: { bdoIds: SelectedArray  },